# Django model for time-table like objects

Tags: python, django, database

I have to implement a time-table. It would display like a table in HTML. The table would look like follows:

```
| Subject | Timing | Teacher |
|---      |---     |---      |
| Maths   | 9-10   | Abc     |
| English | 10-11  | Qwe     |
| Science | 11-12  | Zxc     |
```

I already have a `section` model which will contain this `time-table` model. The `section` model also has `ManyToManyField` for its teachers, and a `ManyToManyField` for its subjects.

```
class Section(models.Model):
    subject = ManyToManyField(Subject)
    teacher = ManyToManyField(Teacher)
    time_table = ManyToManyField(TimeTable)
```

For the timings I have created the below model.

```
class Timing(models.Model):
    time_start = models.TimeField()
    time_end   = models.TimeField()
```

My first try for creating a time-table model is:

```
class TimeTable(models.Model):
    subject = ForeignKey(Subject)
    timing  = ForeignKey(Timing)
    teacher = ForeignKey(Teacher)
```

Is there a better implementation for creating these type of tables?

Also, I feel my time-table model is not perfect because I'm using not constraining the subject and teacher choices to those that are only available for that section.

Comment: Do sections have teachers, or do sections have classes that have teachers?

Comment: @mipadi sections have teachers. There is just one class. Therefore I have to implement only sections.

Comment: Is there one teacher per subject per section?

Comment: Yes there is one teacher per subject per section. But since one section can have many teachers and one teacher can have many sections, thus I've added it as a `ManyToManyfield`

Answer (score 1):

Here is my implementation

#### models.py

```
class TimeTable(models.Model):
    DAYS_OF_THE_WEEK = (
        ('1', 'Понедельник'),
        ('2', 'Вторник'),
        ('3', 'Среда'),
        ('4', 'Четверг'),
        ('5', 'Пятница'),
        ('6', 'Суббота'),
        ('7', 'Воскресеньe')
    )
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    day = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=DAYS_OF_THE_WEEK)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Расписание'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Расписания'


class TimeTableItem(models.Model):
    time_table = models.ForeignKey(TimeTable, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    subject = models.ForeignKey(Subject, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    teacher = models.ForeignKey(Teacher, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    start_time = models.TimeField()
    end_time = models.TimeField()

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Предмет:{}, Учитель:{}, Время:{}-{}'.format(self.subject, self.teacher, self.start_time, self.end_time)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('start_time',)
```

#### admin.py

```
class TimeTableItemInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = models.TimeTableItem
    raw_id_fields = ['subject']
    extra = 1


@admin.register(models.TimeTable)
class TimeTableAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['course', 'day']
    inlines = [TimeTableItemInline]
```